# Django ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Internal Server Error: /ico/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png

Tags: python, html, django, django-1.4

My django application is currently sending error reports when users try to acces pages of the site that does nor exist, which is how its supposed to be.

But when I try to use the django application though my tablets(Android and Apple) I get an email with this error

```
[Django] ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Internal Server Error: /ico/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
```

My html header looks like this

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}" type="x-icon" />
```

My static file path just in case.

```
|-- static
    |-- css
    |-- img
    |-- js
    |-- ico
        |-- favicon.png
        |-- apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
    |-- favicon.ico
```

I did some googleing and found [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/error-reporting/#errors) regarding error reporting and tried adding the following to the settings.py but had no luck.

```
import re
IGNORABLE_404_URLS = (
    re.compile(r'^/ico/apple-touch-icon-precomposed\.png$'),
    re.compile(r'^/favicon\.ico$'),
    re.compile(r'^/robots\.txt$'),
)
```

How can I fix this to avoid getting emails about the Server Error on the favicons.

Does anyone have an idea on this? Have I missed out on anything

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1):

It might be funny but this is how I solved my problem.

I added the extra few bit into my header. Make sure to load the smallest image first, for more regarding this you can [read here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}" type="x-icon" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="{% static 'ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png' %}" type="image/png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="{% static 'ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png' %}" type="image/png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="{% static 'ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png' %}" type="image/png">
<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'ico/favicon.png' %}" type="image/png">
```

And finally I added the extra images into static

```
|-- static
    |-- css
    |-- img
    |-- js
    |-- ico
        |-- favicon.png
        |-- apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
        |-- apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png
        |-- apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png
        |-- apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png
    |-- favicon.ico
```

Hope this is usefull to someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

I think apple devices make those requests if the device owner adds the site to it.

This is the equivalent of the favicon. To resolve, add 2 100×100 png files, save it as apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png and apple-touch-icon.png and upload it to the root directory of the server.

For me the error has gone.